# Does the ListBox in MFC framework have limited item length?

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, listbox

Dose the ListBox in MFC framework have limited item length? If so, what is the limit?

Comment: Why do you need to know?

Comment: Because I want to put a lot of data into a list box, but it didn't succeed all the time. And I want to write a custom control to extend it. Before I start to work, I want to make sure that it is the control's problem not the way I use it.

Comment: Do you mean the number of characters in a single item, or the maximum number of items in the listbox?

Comment: Of course, there is always a limit; if not the ListBox then the OS. You can never put in infinite amount of data into something. What do you think, Turing tapes do exist?

Comment: Thank you, I want to know the limit number of items in the listbox. And if there is a limit, maybe I can write a listbox with a file cache to meet my need. And I have already to do so. Thank you all again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a limit. For an owner draw one it's probably related to the limits of the GDI coordinate system.

However, long before you reach the ListBox limit, you reach the limit of good UI. Wide horizontally scrollable listboxes aren't easy to use. If you have very wide data to expose, consider another UI abstraction, like a tree or multicolumn list, and consider what kind of data your user actually needs to see.

Martyn